# Adding new line after bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

I am proxying the function console.log to add some information to my logs and I am as well checking whether the information being logged is an object. I do this to avoid getting a log entry of the sort

```
2016-12-17 (22:12:51) > [object Object]
```

Code works fine when passing arguments that are not objects. For example, the command

```
console.log("hello","world");
```

prints

```
2016-12-17 (22:23:53) > hello
2016-12-17 (22:23:53) > world
```

But if I pass an object as well, the code will fail to insert a new line after the object. For example, the command

```
console.log("hello",{world:true,hello:{amount:1,text:"hello"}},"world");
```

prints

```
2016-12-17 (22:27:32) > hello
2016-12-17 (22:27:32) > { world: true, hello: { amount: 1, text: hello } } 2016-12-17 (22:27:33) > world
```

(note the missing line break after displaying the object).

**Code**

**JQuery 3.1.1**

**main.js:**

```
(function (proxied) {
    function displayArg(argument){
        var result= "";
        if(typeof argument == "object") {
            result += "{ ";
            for (i in argument) {
                result += i + ": ";
                result += (displayArg(argument[i]));
                result += ", "
            }
            result = result.substring(0,result.length - 2);
            result += " }";
            return result;
        } else {
            return argument;
        }
    }

    console.log = function () {
        var result = [];
        for (i in arguments) {
            var d = new Date();
            result[i] = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1)  + "-" + d.getDate() +
                " (" + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ") > ";
            result[i] += displayArg(arguments[i]);
            result[i] += "\n";
        }
        return proxied.apply(this, result);
    }
})(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **TL;DR** change the iterator variables so they don't share name, or add a "var" to the loop definition to make sure they don't escape your desired scope.

It turns out that the for loops from (my own) *console.log* and *displayArg* were "sharing" the value of the iterator *i*. This is because by not declaring the iterator variable, the scope was broader than what I needed. To clarify, look at this example:

```
console.log({isThis:"real life"},"hello","world")
```

The code from *console.log* will add a date to the beginning of *result[0]* and then call *displayArg(arguments[0])*, *arguments[0]* being *{isThis:"real life"}*. That function, will iterate over the objects properties, thus *i* will be assigned the value *isThis*. After the function returns, the value of *i* will not go back to *0*. Instead, *i* will be *isThis* and as a consequence, the line

```
result[i] += "\n";
```

translates to

```
result[isThis] += "\n"
```

instead of

```
result[0] += "\n"
```

Probably the most sensible solution was to add a *var* in the for declaration of the iterators. The following code works as expected:

```
(function (proxied) {
    function displayArg(argument){
        var result= "";
        if(typeof argument == "object") {
            result += "{ ";
            for (var i in argument) {
                result += i + ": ";
                result += (displayArg(argument[i]));
                result += ", "
            }
            result = result.substring(0,result.length - 2);
            result += " }";
            return result;
        } else {
            return argument;
        }
    }

    console.log = function () {
        var result = [];
        for (var i in arguments) {
            var d = new Date();
            result[i] = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1)  + "-" + d.getDate() +
                " (" + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ") > ";
            result[i] += displayArg(arguments[i]);
            result[i] += "\n";
        }
        return proxied.apply(this, result);
    }
})(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding objective but what about something along the lines of the following oversimplified override:

```
var oldLog = console.log;

console.log= function(){
   var d= new Date(),
       dateString = // process string

   .....
   for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++){
      oldLog(dateString, arguments[i]);          
   }

}
```

Comment: I did analyze the possibility of calling the previous definition individually per argument, that would save me the handling of new lines. As a matter of fact, it is not too hard from my code to call the function per argument (result[i]) instead of making just one call. However, the code will use information returned by console.log, and calling it several times internally when the user only called it once might bring me more complications than solutions.